# Drawing Mulitple Views with Paths (Android)

Tags: java, android

I've been having a lot of issues drawing multiple paths in the same relative layout. What happens is that all my paths are drawn on the same spot they were originally drawn. Instead I want to shrink each drawn path/canvas and have them displayed side by side on the page.

My code to draw the paths looks like

```
    for (int x=0; x < paths.size(); x++){
        DrawView dw = new CustomView(this);
        dw.path = paths.get(x);
        dw.paint = paints.get(x);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (x == 0){

        } else {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, x-1);
        }
        dw.setId(x);
        layout.addView(dw, params);
    }
```

I followed other suggestions for `TextView`s to add an custom layout parameter to display each `TextView` below each other but this does not appear to work for dynamically drawn paths.

Note: `CustomView` is a class that extends View and overwrites the `onDraw` method to draw out my paths.

EDIT:

If it helps my custom class looks like

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    public Path path;
    public Paint paint = new Paint();

    public CustomView(Context context){
        super(context);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it necessary for you to use a RelativeLayout? If it is not too binding, consider having a LinearLayout which either replaces the RelativeLayout, or is contained within the RelativeLayout. Then you can add all the CustomViews to this LinearLayout, setting the weight field in LinearLayout.LayoutParams to 1.

Alternatively, consider manually setting each CustomView's height to getHeight()/(paths.size()) instead of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: Hi Ajinkya Dahale, thank you for the response. Unfortunately, switching to a LinearLayout and changing each weight to 1 leads to only one path being drawn one the page. Furthermore, I tried using CustomView.getHeight()/(paths.size()) but this has odd effects on path drawing and leads to no image being drawn on the page.

Comment: @user1431282: Maybe a few diagrams of how you want it to look like in the end and how it currently looks would be able to help me understand your problem better.